# How to apply conditional CSS for numeric field?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, conditional-statements

I have scenario like, I have table which generates dynamically. Table may contain number fields as well as text fields. I give a specific CSS to that table. I want that where there is text field in table I give  `text-align: center;` and where there is number field in table I give `text-align: right;` Can I do this applying CSS using single Id/Class? Can we give `if condition` that recognize table fields are number or text in CSS file?

This is my table which is generated dynamically

```
<table class="alignCSS">
<thead>
    <tr>

        <th>
            Doctor Name
        </th>

        <th>
            Amount
        </th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr>

        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Doctor_Name) %>
        // text field here i want to apply center alignment using CSS
        </td>

        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount) %>

        //number field here i want to apply right alignment using CSS
        </td>

    </tr>
<% } %>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Show your code that is generating the table.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have edited my que. and add dynamically table generated code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
    <%= Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Doctor_Name) %>
</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">
    <%= Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount) %>
</td>
```

or if you already have CSS class defined with those rules:

```
<td class="center">
    <%= Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Doctor_Name) %>
</td>
<td class="right">
    <%= Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount) %>
</td>
```

Comment: See, I want to use external CSS. And I have number of tables which are going to generate dynamically. So it not possible I go and apply internal CSS in each and every page. That is not preferable way even. So I want to use one global external CSS with condition. Is there any other way????

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is an old question... but) You could pass a value for the class from the controller so the logic for determining the type of a field could be in there.